# Quick sort in Python - changes to the same number

Tags: python, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort in python using the following code:

```
def partition(nums, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(nums)-1

    i, j, pivot = start-1, start, nums[end]

    while j < end:
        if nums[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
        j += 1

    nums[i+1], pivot = pivot, nums[i+1]
    return i+1

def quicksort(nums, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(nums) - 1

    if start <= end:
        pivot = partition(nums, start, end)
        print(pivot)
        quicksort(nums, start, pivot-1)
        quicksort(nums, pivot+1, end)


    return nums
```

However the result is following:
[4, 2, 6, 3] -> [2, 3, 3, 3]

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: From the quick glance, `nums[i+1], pivot = pivot, nums[i+1]` this swap has only half of its effect. Reassigning pivot does nothing outside the function.

Comment: When you do `nums[i+1], pivot = pivot, nums[i+1]`, you set an element of your list to the value of `pivot`, but you don't set another element of your list to the value of `nums[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
nums[i+1], pivot = pivot, nums[i+1]
```

with:

```
nums[i+1], nums[end] = pivot, nums[i+1]
```